# fill_between from a stacked dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
symbol       DAL        MS       QQQ       SPY      TLT  XLE
symbol                                                      
DAL          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN  NaN
MS      0.560979       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN  NaN
QQQ     0.621045  0.789771       NaN       NaN      NaN  NaN
SPY    -0.576444 -0.843485 -0.953304       NaN      NaN  NaN
TLT     0.186840  0.421957  0.333320 -0.347808      NaN  NaN
XLE     0.115093  0.578970  0.559711 -0.701126  0.38047  NaN
```

I then stack and order the dataframe and plot the result as a barchart as follows:

```
dfstacked = corr_df.stack().order()
dfstacked.plot(kind='bar')

symbol  symbol
SPY     QQQ      -0.953304
        MS       -0.843485
XLE     SPY      -0.701126
SPY     DAL      -0.576444
TLT     SPY      -0.347808
XLE     DAL       0.115093
TLT     DAL       0.186840
        QQQ       0.333320
XLE     TLT       0.380470
TLT     MS        0.421957
XLE     QQQ       0.559711
MS      DAL       0.560979
XLE     MS        0.578970
QQQ     DAL       0.621045
        MS        0.789771
```

[image]

What im trying to do now (without success) is to not plot this as a barchart but to instead plot it by filling in the area below and above zero. My guess is I should be using fill_between similar to these examples: [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html):

```
ax.fill_between(dfstacked.index, 0, dfstacked.values, where = dfstacked.values > 0, interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(dfstacked.index, dfstacked.values, 0, where = dfstacked.values < 0, interpolate=True)
```

I get the error: `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
dfstacked = dfstacked.reset_index(drop=True)
print dfstacked
0    -0.953304
1    -0.843485
2    -0.701126
3    -0.576444
4    -0.347808
5     0.115093
6     0.186840
7     0.333320
8     0.380470
9     0.421957
10    0.559711
11    0.560979
12    0.578970
13    0.621045
14    0.789771
dtype: float64
```

And then set `axis x` from `multiindex`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


dfstacked = corr_df.stack().order()

ticklabels = dfstacked.index.tolist()

dfstacked = dfstacked.reset_index(drop=True)
print dfstacked


ax = dfstacked.plot()

ax.fill_between(dfstacked.index, 0, dfstacked.values, where = dfstacked.values > 0, interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(dfstacked.index, dfstacked.values, 0, where = dfstacked.values < 0, interpolate=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)    
plt.show()
```

[image: graph01]

Answer (score 4):

You can play with the `width` and `edgecolor` parameters of `plt.bar` to get something that look less like an histogram.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[-3,-1,5,3,4,2]

plt.bar(x,y,color='b',width=1,edgecolor="none")
```

[image]

Comment: nice solution, simple and straightforward

Comment: Great suggestion. Works quite well. I've accepted the answer which uses fill_between, but this is still a really great (and simple) suggestion. Upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is a bit off. In your case `fill_between` needs X values, then value of Y to which you want to fill, and then your Y values.

Here is a little example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
x = np.arange(len(s))
plt.fill_between(x,0,s)
```

[image: area under curve]

Then you can use your `index` to `set_xticklabels`.